# Parse not updating the core data Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to make changes to the data already stored in the core data in Parse. But it is not making the necessary changes. And I looked at the documentation for parse regarding objects here: https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects. And it seems that I am doing exactly what the document is telling me to do. Maybe I am missing something? Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var products = PFObject(className:"Products")
        products["name"] = "ice cream"
        products["description"] = "Strawberry"
        products["price"] = 4.99
        products.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (success, error) -> Void in
            if (success) {
                println("Object saved with id \(products.objectId)")
            } else {
                println("Not successful!")
                print(error)
            }
        }

//ignore the code below this line for now please :)

        var query = PFQuery(className: "Products")

        query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("7lmnxHxibK", block: { (object: PFObject?, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print(error)
            } else if let product = object {
                print("YO")
                product["description"] = "Rocky Road"
                product["price"] = 5.99
                products.saveInBackground()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

So the code above created an object with the ID `7lmnxHxibK`. The `description` being `Strawberry`, the `name` being `ice cream`, and the `price` being `4.99`. Which worked as it should. So now as an attempt to change the attributes in the object with the ID `7lmnxHxibK`, I wrote the following code:

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "Products")

query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("7lmnxHxibK", block: { (object: PFObject?, error) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
        print(error)
    } else if let product = object {
        print("YO")
        product["description"] = "Rocky Road"
        product["price"] = 5.99
        products.saveInBackground()
    }
})
```

This code should make the necessary changes to the object with the id `7lmnxHxibK`. But rather than making the necessary changes to the object's attributes, it is creating a new object with it's `description`, `name`, and `price` all being `(undefined)`. Anybody have a solution to fix this?

Comment: hehe, are you following Rob Percival's course?

Comment: Just to make sure, you are trying to edit that 'object' which in this case is the strawberry icecream right?

Comment: Haha, yea I am. Are you as well? If so, what do you think about it?

Comment: You have a type-o, products != product in your closure.

Comment: OOOO. So I should be doing `product.saveInBackground()` not `products.saveInBackground()` right?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `products.saveInBackground()` to `product.saveInBackground()`. Also by the time you call your second query parse may not be done saving the object for the first time.